# Extract column from matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, data-extraction

I would like to extract a column from a matrix class which has variable `A` implemented as a `<vector<vector<T> >` like this `my_matrix(,2)` and that should extract my second column. Also I don't want a function name get_col because I already used operator() overloading to extract rows. I tried:

```
template<class T>
vector<T> & operator()(void, const int& col){
    vector<T> Result(rows,0);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;++i)
        Result[i]=this->A[i][col];
    return Result;
}
```

any suggestions?

The class consists of:

```
template <class T> class QMatrix{
public:
    int rows; 
    int cols;
    vector<vector<T> > A;
```

Comment: This syntax is impossible in C++.

Comment: maybe we can use a trick :)

Answer (score 3):

`func(,2)` is not legal in C++, there's no way to accomplish that.

You could use `operator()` to access a cell in the matrix, and have one `row` function that retrieves an entire row, and one `col` function that retrieves a column.

Or you can overload `operator[]` for getting a column, but I suspect this will confuse your users quite a bit. I suspect overloading `operator()` to get a single row will also confuse your users, it's not very C++-y.

Comment: I went with overloading the operator(). (int, int) for the elements of the matrix and (int) for the row

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this fast (may work for not-to-large matrices) is to store in memory 2 layouts: one for the matrix and one for its transpose. In this way, you have sequential access, and the accessing will be pretty darn fast (i.e., accessing the `k`-th row will be equivalent to a pointer `*row` access from `k*col_num` to `(k+1)*col_num`, whereas accessing the `k`-th column will be accessing the other pointer `*col` from `k*row_num` to `(k+1)*row_num`.

You lose in storage space (i.e., need to duplicate the elements), but gain in access time. If you deal with relatively small matrices, but frequent readouts, this may be a way to go.

Otherwise, you can just store your matrix as a 1-D vector, and access it via 2-D indexes, like `M[i][j] = vec[i*col_num + j]`.

Just do some benchmarking and see what works best for your usage case.

Comment: this is an interesting idea.. make a transpose and then get the rows with A(int). You'd have to transpose every matrix though and update its tranpose (or even worse compute a new transpose) everytime you change the matrix.

Comment: This has big disadvantages if you change elements often or sequentially, because you well have tons of cache misses

Comment: @moldovean another idea is to use the approach I mentioned, but lazy evaluate, i.e. update the transpose only when needed. Of course, it is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing arrays columns is very expensive compared to line accessing because of the layout of the array in the memory. That makes it good that it is ugly to access arrays column by column in C++.

Defining member functions or overloading operators just hides the only way to accomplish it: Go to every row and go to the column you want to access.

You could how ever define a function that returns a `vector` which holds pointers or references (you will need to use a wrapper like `std::reference_wrapper` for that) to the elements of a specific column. To create that vector you again need to access every subvector and get the reference/ptr to the n-th element.